# Manipulating data using JSON parse/stringify

Tags: javascript, json

I have a question about manipulating JSON data using Javascript and stringify/parse. In the below example, I create a JSON string, then use parse to convert it back into an object. After doing that, what I want to do is delete an item with a certain ID, and the only way I can find to do it is to loop through the entire array and delete the element from the array once I find a match. This doesn't seem very efficient. Is there a better way to do this?

```
var employees = [];

//build the array
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    var player = { "id": i, "salary": i*1000000 };
    employees.push(player);
}

json_employees = JSON.stringify({employees: employees}); //convert to json string
alert(json_employees); //display the new string

var obj = JSON.parse(json_employees); //convert back to a Javascript object

for (var j=0; j < obj.employees.length; j++) { // loop through the array
    if (obj.employees[j].id === 5) // is it the employee with id 5?
        obj.employees.splice(j, 1); // remove the fifth item
}

json_modified_employees = JSON.stringify({employees: obj.employees}); //convert back to json string
alert(json_modified_employees); //display the new string
```

Comment: In this case, you're pushing employees onto the array in order of id.  Is that true in your actual code as well?

Comment: Without looping? no... well... you can regex hack the string, but that's probably worse than looping through the array...

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON? You have the same problem trying to find the item in the original `employees` array, don't you?

Comment: Not sure how you could do it without looping, but if you're going to work with lots of object arrays, you might want to consider looking at something like http://hugoware.net/Projects/jLinq

Answer (score 0):

You could store the employees in an object, with a key of their `id`, something like this:

```
// create a store object
var employees = {};

//build the array
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    var player = { "id": i, "salary": i*1000000 };
    // add item to store object with a key of 'pk' + i
    employees['pk' + i] = player;
}

json_employees = JSON.stringify({employees: employees}); //convert to json string
alert(json_employees); //display the new string

var obj = JSON.parse(json_employees); //convert back to a Javascript object

// remove the required item (in this case number 5)
delete obj.employees['pk' + 5];

json_modified_employees = JSON.stringify({employees: obj.employees}); //convert back to json string
alert(json_modified_employees); //display the new string
```

If you then wanted to iterate over your employees, you would

```
for (var key in employees) {
    if (employees.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        alert(employees[key].id)
    }
}
```

Comment: The ID will not necessarily match the index of the array. Thanks for all of the great answers, especially Dve!